# How can I use a String in an URL?

Tags: rest, jersey

I'm trying to create Web Service where I can send a stardog request using a HTTP GET method. My problem is that the stardog request are using a few symbol that aren't allowed in a URL, like `?` or `;` and I'm trying to not force the user to manually convert it to `%3F` or `%3B`.

So I want my URL to look like this :

```
localhost:8080/WebServiceTest/query?select="SELECT * WHERE {?s ?p ?o}"
```

My Jersey annotations are the following:

```
@GET
@Path("/query")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
public String execQuery(@QueryParam("select") String selectQuery, @QueryParam("update") String updateQuery) {
```

Does anyone know if this is possible? And if it is, how can I do that?

Comment: What is the client for this JAX-RS resource? A web browser? It should automatically URL encode any input. Jersey will revert this encoding so `selectQuery` will contain the correct input.

Comment: It will probably be a web browser, but it might also be cURL or any other tools using to transfering data. The web browser isn't encoding the ?, I guess it's because it is understanding them as a query parameter, when it should be a simple symbol.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Javascript/ECMAScript 5.1++ on client side you can convert a string to a uri string format. Use the method

```
encodeURIComponent(str);
```

which is explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

It is also possible to replace the ? ; chars by their %-represetation. (In the case of using cUrl)

```
(SPACE) !   "   #   $   %   &   '   (   )   *   +   ,   /   :   ; 
%20     %21 %22 %23 %24 %25 %26 %27 %28 %29 %2A %2B %2C %2F %3A %3B     

=   ?   @   [   ]
%3D %3F %40 %5B %5D
```

Comment: I would like to use Javascript, the problem is that I'm not sure how the user will get to this URL. If he just type the URL in his browser, I can't use JS.

Comment: That's correct. If a user types the URL in the browsers url field and the browser does no automatic url encoding, the text will be sent over http and probably misinterpreted by the receiver or a proxy. I do not know a method to avoid this. Perhaps someone here on SO knows a method to intercept with the browsers http sending (perhaps by implementing a plugin) but that would be nessecary for all used browsers. I think this would be out of scope. Perhaps there are plugins that do urlencoding automatically. But allowing the user to provide code is a massive security risk. You know? ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess the user will have to encode it himself, then. And yes, I get why this is a pretty dangerous thing to do, but I'm only doing what my boss want me to do.

Comment: I'm a developer and also a CEO of a very small company. One of our employers pointed me to that video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKorP55Aqvg . It's amazing, it's like a deja vu ;-).